# Moving photos from MacBook download folder to desktop and Photos

Tags: macbook-pro

I would like to move photographs from a professional photographer to my desktop as well as into Photo. Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Where are the photos stored right now (from where to you want to move them)? Can‘t you just drag&drop them like any other files in Finder?

Answer (score 2):

Select all photos you want to move (in downloads folder in Finder), go to Edit menu-> cut. Go to desktop and in Finder, Edit menu-> paste.

For photos, Go to File -> import -> navigate to downloads and select using command-click or shift- click and hit review for import. Then finalise.

Comment: Simply drag&drop‘ing them might also work :-) And of course using the sharing option in the context menu to trigger Photos import from Finder.

Answer (score -1):

Drag and drop the files into iCloud, ftp or box.com

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on *how* they can do what you're suggesting. Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.